# Match multiple patterns from "pattern file" in Paragraph-Mode

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have an input file which has to be searched for different matches in a paragraph and moved to an output-file with the whole paragraph when matched.

One thing is that the order of the output should reflect the input.
So I have to search one paragraph against *all* patterns from the pattern match file (one pattern per line), and if *one* pattern matches it should stop further matching for that paragraph and move the matched paragraph to an output file, and skip processing to the next paragraph.

The input file:

```
DFJKHDKQW
YYYYYYYYYYYY
SDFLKJHSDKLFH

DSFLKHSDLKFH
DFIHERFW
ADFKJH
OIGHRFGH
XXXXXXXXXXXX
SDKFLJH

DFLKHSDFKLH
SDSDJKLFHSDK

OIHGSDFG
AAAAAAAA
LFKHFGJKDGH
KLJHLUG

DFSDKLF
YYYYYYYYYYYY
```

Pattern Match file:

```
AAAAAAAA
YYYYYYYYYYYY
XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Expected Output:

```
DFJKHDKQW
YYYYYYYYYYYY
SDFLKJHSDKLFH

DSFLKHSDLKFH
DFIHERFW
ADFKJH
OIGHRFGH
XXXXXXXXXXXX
SDKFLJH

OIHGSDFG
AAAAAAAA
LFKHFGJKDGH
KLJHLUG

DFSDKLF
YYYYYYYYYYYY
```

I'm facing a bunch of `awk` problems now which are way over my head:

1. Use an input file for matching patterns
2. Rotate over paragraphs and "stop/jump to next paragraph" on first match
3. Copy matched paragraph to output file.
4. Delete matched paragraph in input (optional because I can do this via a `diff` between the two files later).

Comment: Never use the word "pattern" when trying to match text as it's ambiguous, use "regexp" or "string". e.g. does a **pattern** of "a.c" match "abc" or "a.c" or both? - there's no way to tell given  the word "pattern" but a **string** of "a.c" matches "a.c" only while a **regexp** of "a.c" matches both "abc" and "a.c". So please [edit] your question to replace "pattern" with either "string" or "regexp", whichever it is you mean, and also state whether the matches have to be full or can be partial (e.g. "the" matches "other" in a partial match but not in a full match).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know about the "paragraph" mode, the following approach should work. It will first parse the "patterns" file and then the actual input. Output is printed to the console as usual, but can of course be redirected to a file:

```
awk -v ORS="\n\n" 'NR==FNR{pat[++npat]=$0;next}
                   {for (i=1;i<=npat;i++) {if (index($0,pat[i])) {print;next}}}' patterns.txt RS="" input.txt
```

- This will first of all set the output record separator to two newlines, ensuring that printed paragraphs are separated by an empty line as in the input.
- When processing the first file (where `FNR`, the per-file line-counter is equal to `NR`, the global line counter), we simply store all patterns in an array variable `pat`.
- For the second file, the record separator is set to empty, which instructs `awk` to run in "paragraph mode". Then we iterate over all patterns and look explicitly if they are found in the input record via the `index()` function.

**Note**

- This solution will perform "partial string matching", meaning a paragraph will be considered a match if any one of the "patterns" is encountered anywhere in one of the lines.
- The `index()` function is used because that will ensure *literal* string matching even in those cases where your "search patterns" contain characters that are special to regular expressions. If you want to actually use regular expression matchin, use `if ($0 ~ pat[i])` instead.

Comment: @T-One FYI this is an example of a solution that does partial string matching as opposed to full line string matching like the other existing answers. So far we don't know which type of matching you want so different people are guessing different things.

Comment: @Ed Morton i think i go the regex-way via if ($0 ~ pat[i]) so i can match over multiple lines too. But i'm still playing with the different solutions provided.

Comment: @T-One using a regexp is unrelated to matching over multiple lines. You can do string matching or regexp matching on a single line or on multiple lines.

Comment: @Ed Morton how would i do multi line string matching in this example? I thought it's one string in the match file each line? With Regex i can add the line breaks in the match file, can i do this with a string as well?

Comment: Yes, just have the text in the match file be multi-line blocks separated by empty lines, just like in the file you're matching against. [Accept an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to the question you asked and then ask a new question with THAT as the sample input/output if you'd like help with it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to do full-line string matching, this is what you need:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    ORS = "\n\n"
    FS = "\n"
}
NR==FNR {
    tgts[$0]
    next
}
{
    out = "unmatched"
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i in tgts) {
            out = "matched"
            break
        }
    }
    print > out
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk targets RS= file
```

```
$ ls *matched
matched  unmatched
```

```
$ head -100 *matched
==> matched <==
DFJKHDKQW
YYYYYYYYYYYY
SDFLKJHSDKLFH

DSFLKHSDLKFH
DFIHERFW
ADFKJH
OIGHRFGH
XXXXXXXXXXXX
SDKFLJH

OIHGSDFG
AAAAAAAA
LFKHFGJKDGH
KLJHLUG

DFSDKLF
YYYYYYYYYYYY


==> unmatched <==
DFLKHSDFKLH
SDSDJKLFHSDK
```

If you need to do a regexp instead of string match and/or partial instead of full match or something else then you'd need a different solution (and please update your question to better state your requirements).

Comment: I'm parsing a logfile with all kinds of stuff in different "paragraphs", i'm still playing with the given solutions and try to warp my head around the awk-wizardry. But thanks in advance, it helps me a lot with learning more advanced uses of awk.

Answer (score 2):

To match patterns in *`match`* input each as single separate pattern against the *`infile`* input, try:

```
awk -F'\n' '!input && !matches[$0]{ next; };
    { for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
          if($i in matches) { print sep $0; sep=ORS; break; };
      };
    }' match input=1 RS= infile
```

---

or to match patterns in *`match`* input as a pattern block against the *`infile`* input (add one block same as in *`match`* input to *`infile`* to verify), try:

```
awk -v RS= '!input && !matches[$0]{ next; }; ($0 in matches)' match input=1 infile
```